# Getting any company and people profile from LinkedIn API (REST)

Tags: linkedin-api

I would like to get public profile for any company and people from linkedIn using LinkedIn API. Which API I need to use and how can I use?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to be more specific on the values/details you are trying to access, but let's start with finding company profile details.

## 1 - Start here and review their API documentation:

https://www.linkedin.com/developers/

LinkedIn has made a lot of changes lately, so you'll need to be ready to migrate from V1 to V2 if you already have something built previously.

## 2 - Create your App and apply for the [Marketing Partner Program](https://business.linkedin.com/marketing-solutions/marketing-partners/become-a-partner/marketing-developer-program), and review the documentation here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/migrations/marketing-permissions-migration

That should be a good starting point, but if you could be more specific with what you need, I could provide some more direct answers.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your reply and good advice. We are developing an application for our sales people to view their customer profiles (company background, contact details) and key personal information (such as name, employment history) in their companies. I want to leverage using LinkedIn APi. 

As understood, LinkedIn company/Organization API is meant for my own company information management on LinkedIn. But I am not sure if I can get other company details from the APi.

I have also applied partner program 2 days ago but no response from LinkedIn. Appreciate if you help me. Thanks.

Comment: Unless the user authenticates and accepts connecting to your platform, you won't be able to pull any user data.  I also don't believe you can pull employment history/company details through this method either: 
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api - LinkedIn has put a ton of restrictions on accessing this type of data through the API.